# Add a magic link for revisions

Tags: feature-request, comments, revisions-list

I just wrote [this comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11052/german-word-equivalents-for-prison-in-a-metaphorical-sense#comment27917_11059) and thought to myself: We got a link to the edit, why not for revisions too?

> I just edited your sentence from a codeblock (as used on [so]) to a blockquote. This should improve readability. If you don't like it, you can always apply a "rollback" in [revision history](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/11059/revisions)

Thus I propose to add a magic link to the revision history of the post which is commented on in the form of `[revisions]`.

<sub>Sorry for the link to German. I just don't really edit posts here.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This would be very useful, especially if want to point out that there will be edit history, even though there is no such history yet, you will have difficulties creating the link as you cannot just use the browser to right-click and use "Copy Link Location" (FireFox, other browser have similar functionality). So you have to find the id of the question and construct the URL yourself.

I find myself in this situation if I want the OP of a question to update their post, but prevent them from future inserting EDIT or UPDATE, by pointing out that there is (or will be) edit history and, that that kind of chit-chat is irrelevant and distracting for all future visitors.